# Rather weird css/opacity/hover question

Tags: css, opacity

Sorry for the title, I really couldn't think of how to simplify this problem.

Now, the problem is this: I have a row of thumbnail images in a div:

```
<div id="daumen">

<a href='#' class='gsc_thumb_row'>
    <img src='image1.jpg' class='thumbnails' />
</a>

<a href='#' class='gsc_thumb_row'>
    <img src='image2.jpg' class='current-thumbnail'/>
</a>

<a href='#' class='gsc_thumb_row'>
     <img src='image3.jpg' class='thumbnails' />
</a>

</div>
```

(I can't change the HTML, it's delivered by a script.)

As you may have noticed, two of these have the class "thumbnails", and one "current-thumbnail".

What I'd like to happen is this: 
By default, all images except for the current thumbnail have an opacity of 0.5.
On mouseover, the opacity should change to 1.

The CSS I'm using:

```
#daumen {

    }

#daumen img:hover{
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        -moz-opacity:1;
        -khtml-opacity: 1;
        opacity: 1;
    }

#daumen img{
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

.current-thumbnail a:link{
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        -moz-opacity:1;
        -khtml-opacity: 1;
        opacity: 1;
    }        

.thumbnails {

    }

.current-thumbnail {

}
```

​

So far, all of this works except that the current thumbnail's opacity is also set to 0.5 - how can I avoid this?

I'm sure there's a very simple solution, but I've been fiddling around with the CSS for far to long already.

I put it in a Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6DGAx/

Thanks in advance,
Cenk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a more specific selector:

```
#daumen .current-thumbnail a:link{
```

Also, **make sure your markup matches your CSS** because your `img` has that class.........

Comment: To clarify, styles are given priority based on how specific the CSS selector is. By appending the #daumen id to the front of the class selector, it becomes more specific than the "#daumen img" selector, and it's opacity is used.

Comment: YES! This and Hrishi's answer combined finally made it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, always define your pseudo link selectors in this order: Link, Visited, Active, Hover.  LVHA, to remember it I made up Las Vegas Hookers Association, never been there, but heard they had business cards.  a {} without the pseudo selector will define the defaults for all of them and should be put first.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
#daumen .thumbnail{
```

instead of

```
#daumen img{
```

if you want to select the class thumbnail

Comment: Thanks so much, this and meder's answer worked perfectly :)
I could only set one answer as accepted, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all you target your element wrongly, because there is no `a` inside an element with class `current-thumbnail` as you current rule suggests (`.current-thumbnail a:link`)

it should be `#daumen .current-thumbnail`